# How to find missing sequence number?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with NVARCHAR2 data type. It increases in sequential value by one, and has the pattern "D2017\S\S\S\S" , starts at 0000 and continues up. Right now I have values all the way to D20179999, but I'm missing 10 values from D20170001 to D20179999, how can I find those values?

Comment: ,your question is not clear.Right now you have D20179999.But you missing D20170001 to D20179999.Clearly explain

Comment: info only but will this work on oracle ? --  SELECT LEFT([MyField],8) , COUNT(LEFT([MyField],8))
  FROM MyTable 
 group by LEFT([MyField],8)  
   HAVING COUNT(LEFT([MyField],8)) < 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need. First your should generate range from `D20170001` to `D20179999`. Then you have to right join this with your sequential column and find the `null` to get the missing range.

```
select * from your_table y
right join  
(select 'D2017'||lpad(to_char(level),4,'0') as c_range
      from dual connect by level < 10000) dt
on y.<range_column>=dt.c_range
where y.<range_column> is null
```

Edit: As per @mathguy, for better performance, use

```
select * from 
(select 'D2017'||lpad(to_char(level),4,'0') as c_range
      from dual connect by level < 10000) dt
 where dt.c_range not in (select <range_column> from your_table)
```

I replicated it for 10 values, but you can extend it similarly for 10000.

```
with rt (e_range) as (
select 'D20179990' from dual union all
select 'D20179991' from dual union all
select 'D20179992' from dual union all
select 'D20179994' from dual union all
select 'D20179995' from dual union all
select 'D20179997' from dual union all
select 'D20179998' from dual union all
select 'D20179999' from dual)
select c_range from rt
right join (select 'D2017999'||to_char(level) as c_range from dual connect by level < 10) dt
on rt.e_range=dt.c_range
where rt.e_range is null
```

Output

```
C_RANGE
D20179993
D20179996
```

Comment: Right join does about double the amount of work needed for this. A better solution is to generate all the values from smallest to largest like you did, and then to add `where c_range not in (select op_column from op_table)`

Comment: Good suggestion. But as it is probably for 10000 rows, I hardly think it would matter much but yes, should follow best performance approach wherever possible. Anyways edited the answer to accommodate this approach as well.

Comment: Don't underestimate joining 10k rows to 10k rows, that's 100 million combinations to consider!

Comment: Would these be two separate queries or one together? So I have data already existing, from 'D20170000' to 'D20179999' but there were a lot of deletions throughout and instead o f having the 10000 values that I should have if everything was done right, I only have 3050 values and I need to find the 7950 values that don't exist in the system. Is that better description on the problem?

Comment: No these are same queries. You can go ahead with any of it.

Comment: @mathguy - I just did a poc on my local machine on both the queries for almost 10K rows. The explain plan and execution time is exactly the same. So as I understood for 10K * 10K rows, it hardly matter.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm trying it now, and I think I have entered what you've helped with, but I get a SQL command not properly ended error. Also, I'm a bit confused on your select statements, entering the 'D20179991' and on. You left out D20179993, etc. but how would you know to leave those out, since that is the output I'm trying to find?

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM (    SELECT 'D2017' || LPAD (TO_CHAR (LEVEL), 4, '0') AS c_range
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10000) dt
 WHERE dt.c_range NOT IN (SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER FROM WH_PROJECT_CASE)
with rt (e_range) as (select 'D20179990' from dual union all
select 'D20179991' from dual union all
select 'D20179992' from dual union all
select 'D20179994' from dual union all

Comment: select 'D20179995' from dual union all
select 'D20179997' from dual union all
select 'D20179998' from dual union all
sleect 'D20179999' from dual)
select c_range from rt
right join (select 'D2017999'||to_char(level) as c_range from dual connect by level <10) dt
on rt.e_range=dt.c_range
where rt.e_range is null

Comment: sorry for the bad format, I was trying to copy my edit sql query to see what I was missing/getting wrong and not filling out properly

Comment: do u get any error when u run `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 'D2017' || LPAD (TO_CHAR (LEVEL), 4, '0') AS c_range FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10000) dt WHERE dt.c_range NOT IN (SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER FROM WH_PROJECT_CASE) ` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137018/discussion-between-confusedbeginner-and-utsav).